# Show only unique tags

Tags: php, wordpress

The following shows me all tags names based on all posts, which means I end up with a list with duplications. How do I stop it so that it only shows me unique tags?

```
   <ul>
            <?php
                query_posts('category_name=html');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                    if( get_the_tag_list() ){
                        echo $posttags = get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');
                    }
                endwhile; endif; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
            ?>
   </ul>
```

Comment: You're looking for tags for each post - that's the reason for the duplication. Two possible solutions: Loop the tags and not the posts or put the tags in an array (instead of echo) and use `foreach` to print them. (Prevent duplication by using the tag as the key)

Comment: any chance you provide an answer with an example I can test and in case i will accept it? I'm really stuggling here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying with rob.m, this was the solution we came up with:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        query_posts('category_name=html');
        if (have_posts()) {

            $tags = array();

            while(have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                if(get_the_tag_list()) {
                    foreach(wp_get_post_tags(get_the_ID()) as $tag) {
                        $allTags[$tag->term_id] = $tag;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach($tags as $tag) {
                echo '<li><input class="checkTag" type="checkbox" value="' . $tag->name . '" />' . '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $tag->name . '</li>';
            }
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes but I haven't created an array in the code above. Any chance you can provide an example to test? Thanks

Comment: it doesnt return an array, but a string of HTML

Comment: @davidkonrad yes exactly

Comment: As in '<li>tag1</li><li>tag2</li>...'?

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton no luck, your answer is still outputting all the tags used in the category and not just unique tags

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($posttags);` on the line before the first code comment?

Comment: Just after <?php or where exactly?

Comment: After the line `$posttags = get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');`

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton as you can see, it is repeating the tags unfortunatly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37281/discussion-between-george-brighton-and-rob-m)